# Converting SQL Server to Snowflake SQL, how do I write the INSERT statement to put data from a query into a temp table?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am working on converting a SQL Server query to Snowflake SQL. The code creates a dynamic start and end date, creates the temp table, then inserts the data from the query into the temp table.

Here is the query. When I run individual sections separately, I can create the variables and the temp table and the actual query to pull data also works.

However, I have not been able find the correct syntax for the `INSERT` statement to run correctly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
SET StartDate = (SELECT DATEADD(month, -24, dim.MONTH_BEGIN_DT)
                 FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.DATE_DIMENSION dim
                 WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS date) = dim.CALENDAR_DT);

SET EndDate = (SELECT dim2.MONTH_BEGIN_DT
               FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.DATE_DIMENSION dim2
               WHERE CAST(GETDATE() AS date) = dim2.CALENDAR_DT);

CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.A1C_Min_Max
(
    PAT_ID          VARCHAR(255),
    TEST_CNT        NUMERIC(18,0),
    ORD_ID_MIN      NUMERIC(18,0),
    ORD_ID_MAX      NUMERIC(18,0)
);

INSERT INTO HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.A1C_Min_Max (PAT_ID, TEST_CNT, ORD_ID_MIN, ORD_ID_MAX)  
VALUES 

SELECT
    oprc.PAT_ID,
    COUNT(*) as "TEST_CNT",
    MIN(oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID) as "ORD_ID_MIN",
    MAX(oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID) as "ORD_ID_MAX"
FROM 
    HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.ORDER_PROC oprc
JOIN 
    HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.PAT_ENC enc ON oprc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
INNER JOIN 
    HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.ZC_DISP_ENC_TYPE typ ON enc.ENC_TYPE_C = typ.DISP_ENC_TYPE_C
INNER JOIN 
    HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.CLARITY_EAP eap ON oprc.PROC_ID = eap.PROC_ID
INNER JOIN 
    HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.ORDER_RESULTS ordres ON oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID = ordres.ORDER_PROC_ID
WHERE 
    oprc.ORDERING_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
    AND enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
    AND enc.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288
    AND oprc.proc_id IN (12298843, 12299371, 122127749, 10050764, 12018926, 12037733)
    AND ordres.COMPONENT_ID = 1202098                        -- USE COMPONENT_ID = 1005276 to get ESTIMATED AVERAGE GLUCOSE VALUE    
    AND LEN(ordres.ORD_VALUE) > 1
GROUP BY
    oprc.PAT_ID

SELECT *
FROM HI_DB.STG_EPICCLARITY_PHS.A1C_Min_Max
```

Comment: "I have not been able find the correct snytax"  What is the exact error you get?

Comment: Are you getting an error?  The only thing I see offhand is that you need a semicolon after the INSERT statement and the following SELECT * statement, if you are executing all of these queries at the same time.  But an error message would clarify the issue, I think.

Comment: Thank you all for responding, the suggestion to remove the VALUES key word from the end of the INSERT statement resolved the issue and the code works now.

Answer (score 1):

Try the query without the values keyword.

```html
INSERT INTO A1C_Min_Max (PAT_ID,TEST_CNT,ORD_ID_MIN,ORD_ID_MAX) 
SELECT

    oprc.PAT_ID,
    count(*)  "TEST_CNT",
    MIN(oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID)  "ORD_ID_MIN",
    MAX(oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID)  "ORD_ID_MAX"

FROM ORDER_PROC oprc
JOIN PAT_ENC enc
    ON oprc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID = enc.PAT_ENC_CSN_ID
INNER JOIN ZC_DISP_ENC_TYPE typ
    ON enc.ENC_TYPE_C = typ.DISP_ENC_TYPE_C
INNER JOIN CLARITY_EAP eap
    ON oprc.PROC_ID = eap.PROC_ID
INNER JOIN ORDER_RESULTS ordres
    ON oprc.ORDER_PROC_ID = ordres.ORDER_PROC_ID

WHERE oprc.ORDERING_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
    AND enc.CONTACT_DATE BETWEEN $StartDate AND $EndDate
    AND enc.SERV_AREA_ID = 12288
    AND oprc.proc_id IN (12298843,12299371,122127749,10050764,12018926,12037733)
    AND ordres.COMPONENT_ID = 1202098                        -- USE COMPONENT_ID = 1005276 to get ESTIMATED AVERAGE GLUCOSE VALUE    
    AND LEN(ordres.ORD_VALUE) > 1

GROUP BY
    oprc.PAT_ID;
```

Insert

INSERT [ OVERWRITE ] INTO target_table [ ( target_col_name [ , ... ] ) ]
{ { VALUES ( { value | DEFAULT | NULL } [ , ... ] ) [ , ( ... ) ] } | query }

In a VALUES clause, you can specify the following:

value: Inserts the explicitly-specified value.

DEFAULT: Inserts the default value for the corresponding column in the target table.

NULL: Inserts a NULL value.

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/insert.html#required-parameters

Comment: Removing the VALUES key word worked. The code works now.  Thank you for the help!

Comment: Great! Thank you for cofirming.